# Problem integrating in problem using the Poincaré Lemma

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential-forms

[image]

a) It is easy to show that $d\beta=0$.

b)

$\begin{align}\hat{\mathbb{X}}_t &= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat{\Phi}_t \right) \hat{\Phi}_t^{-1} \\
&= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat{\Phi}_t\right) \left(\frac{x}{t},y,z\right) \\
&=\left(\frac{x}{t},0,0\right)
\end{align}$

Now $\Phi_t^* x =tx$, $\Phi_t^* y =y$, $\Phi_t^* z =z$ , so,

$$ \hat{\Phi}_t^* \beta = \hat{\Phi}_t^* \left(\frac{(t^2x^2-y^2)dy \wedge dz + 2txyt dz \wedge dx}{(t^2x^2+y^2)^2}\right)
\rightarrow \frac{-1}{y^2} dy \wedge dz
$$

So chose $\alpha_0$ to be $(t^2x^2+y^2)^2=\frac{1}{y}dz$

c) First want to compute that $i_{\mathbb{X}_t}\beta$.

$$\begin{align} i_{\mathbb{X}_t} \beta &= i_{\mathbb{X}_t} \left(\frac{(x^2-y^2)}{\rho^4} dy \wedge dz\right) + i_{\mathbb{X}_t}\left(\frac{2xy }{\rho^4} dz \wedge dx\right) \\
&= \left(\frac{(x^2-y^2)}{\rho^4}\right)\left[dy(\mathbb{X}_t)dz - dz(\mathbb{X}_t)dy\right]+\frac{2xy}{\rho^4}[dz(\mathbb{X}_t)dx-dx(\mathbb{X}_t)dz] \\
&= \left(\frac{2xy}{\rho^4}\right)[\frac{-x}{t}dz]
\end{align}$$

Then I have that,

$$\begin{align} \Phi_t^*(i_{\mathbb{X}_t}\beta) &= \frac{-2y}{t}\left(\frac{t^2x^2}{(t^2x^2+y^2)^2}\right)dz \\
&= -2yt \left(\frac{x^2}{(t^2x^2+y^2)^2}\right)dz
\end{align}$$

But this isnt very integrable. Not sure where I have gone wrong or how I should proceed with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just made a silly mistake in the last line of computing $i_{\mathbb{X}_t}\beta$ and grabbed the wrong coefficient.

You should have $2xy$ in the numerator of the first factor instead of $x^2-y^2$. Then what you get after the pullback is easily integrated.

Comment: but $\rho^4=(t^2x^2+y^2)^2$ will be the denominator?

Comment: But $2tx^2$ (times $y$, which you can factor out) is in the numerator. Remember that you're just integrating with respect to $t$.

Comment: I edited this question and I still cannot see how this can be done. I think there is a problem integrating my final line as there is a $t^2$ in the denominator. Theres now a bounty going on the full solution, which I believe could be only one more step.

Comment: It's in the form of $C\frac{du}{u^2}$

Comment: Surely $u^3$ on the denominator?

Comment: No. Cancel the leading $1/t$ if that's causing you a problem. But really, this is a rational function of $t$ and, even if it didn't have an easy $u$ substitution, wouldn't be so bad to integrate.